# k8s fails scheduling of local ssd volume on GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to specify Local SSD in a Google Cloud as a `PersistedVolume`. I followed the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/local-ssd#example_local_pvs) to set up the [automated SSD provisioning](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/local-ssd#running_the_local_volume_static_provisioner), and running `kubectl get pv` returns a valid volume:

```
NAME                CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS      CLAIM     STORAGECLASS   REASON    AGE
local-pv-9721c951   368Gi      RWO            Delete           Available             local-scsi               1h
```

The problem is that I cannot get my pod to bind to it. The `kubectl get pvc` keeps showing this:

```
NAME      STATUS    VOLUME    CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
mapdata   Pending                                       local-scsi     7m
```

and `kubectl get events` gives me these:

```
LAST SEEN   FIRST SEEN   COUNT     NAME                                                KIND                    SUBOBJECT   TYPE      REASON                 SOURCE                        MESSAGE
7m          7m           1         v3tiles.1551c0bbcb23d983                            Service                             Normal    EnsuredLoadBalancer    service-controller            Ensured load balancer
2m          8m           24        maptilesbackend-8645566545-x44nl.1551c0ae27d06fca   Pod                                 Warning   FailedScheduling       default-scheduler             0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't find available persistent volumes to bind.
2m          8m           26        mapdata.1551c0adf908e362                            PersistentVolumeClaim               Normal    WaitForFirstConsumer   persistentvolume-controller   waiting for first consumer to be created before binding
```

What would i need to do to bind that SSD to my pod?  Here's the code I have been experimenting with:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: maptilesbackend
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: maptilesbackend
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: maptilesbackend
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: klokantech/openmaptiles-server
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: maptilesbackend
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /data
            name: mapdata
            readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: mapdata
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mapdata
            readOnly: true
---
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: "local-scsi"
provisioner: "kubernetes.io/no-provisioner"
volumeBindingMode: "WaitForFirstConsumer"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mapdata
spec:
  storageClassName: local-scsi
  accessModes:
    - ReadOnlyMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 300Gi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ReadOnlyMany` doesn't make sense for local SSDs

As per the docs:

> ReadOnlyMany – the volume can be mounted read-only by many nodes

You can't mount a local SSD on many nodes because it's local to one node only.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `accessMode: ReadOnlyMany` does not work in this case. Not sure how to make it work... will post if I find more information.

Comment: As per the following [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) GCEPersistentDisk can be mounted as ReadWriteOnce by a single node or ReadOnlyMany by many nodes. So, for a single node, ReadOnlyMany will not be appropriate.